# SQL Equivalence of Solr Query

Tags: solr-query-syntax, solr6

In my spring boot project, i connect to a solr server. Instead of solr queries I need to use sql queries. I can get expected results for basic queries like `select * from reportCore`, but I cannot add filters or specify field names.
What i would like to to is to find sql query equivalence of the following solr query;

```
id:123 OR reportName:"Promotion"
```

something like

```
select id, price from reportCore where id=123 or reportName="Promotion"
```

Is there a way to do that or do I have to convert sql queries to solr ones. By the way, i use solr 6.1.0

Answer (score 5):

You can use Parallel SQL functionality, present in Solr. Look at the official documentation page: [Parallel SQL Interface](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Parallel+SQL+Interface)